# Couldn't perform a live migration on kvm with the error “Unable to migrate guest: Unable to get index for interface em1: No such device”

Tags: linux, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I configured KVM/qemu on redhat 7. i tried doing a live migration of a guest VM from one host to another, see below the error i was getting:

“Unable to migrate guest: Unable to get index for interface em1: No such device”

my NIC on the source host is em1. it’s configured with an IP of 10.10.10.164/24 since my environment is on 10.10.10.0/24 network.

my NIC on the target host is eno1 configured with an IP of 10.10.10.240/24.

My guest VM ip is 10.10.10.165/24.

I tried doing a live migration, it wasn’t working. it was giving the error i mentioned above. I then created another VM and used NAT option which gave my VM an IP of 192.168.122.252, after which i was able to do live migration.

I want my VM to use 10.10.10.165 and be able to migrate live and not 192.168.122.252 since the network is not defined in my environment. How do i go about it please?

Comment: What was the virtual network configuration of the guest which failed to live migrate?

Comment: Hi Michael, At first, I used a bridged network,  i did a direct bridge to my switch. I then read an article that says i need to configure a virtual network bridge and not a direct bridge which i did, but still, i get the error. so, in summary, the guest network configuration is virtual bridged.